# Errors while making database connection codeigniter phpmyadmin xampp

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter site that I need to connect to the database in phpmyadmin.
This used to work but it no longer does.

The error I get when trying to connect is the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php:92 Stack trace: #0 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\database\DB_driver.php(116): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect() #1 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\database\DB.php(149): CI_DB_driver->initialize() #2 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\core\Loader.php(347): DB(Array, NULL) #3 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\core\Loader.php(1172): CI_Loader->database() #4 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\core\Loader.php(153): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader() #5 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\core\Controller.php(52): CI_Loader->initialize() #6 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\application\controllers\home.php(19): CI_Controller->__construct() #7 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(309): Home->__construct() #8 D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\index.php(202): require_once('D:\Programming\...') #9 {main} thrown in D:\Programming\web\Website_VB\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php on line 92

In my config\database.php I have the following code:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'vbweb';
$db['default']['password'] = 'thepassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbvb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

[image]
I have also made a user vbweb with "thepassword" as password and set it to all priveleges

If you wonder what is in mysql_driver.php, it is the following:

```
function db_pconnect()
    {
        if ($this->port != '')
        {
            $this->hostname .= ':'.$this->port;
        }

        return @mysql_pconnect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error and connect to my database?

Comment: change your default db driver to mysqli.

Comment: do you have enabled `mysqli` extension for php?

Comment: This is uncommented in php.ini -->     extension=php_mysqli.dll